# Authentication in web application using specific domain

Tags: java, authentication

I have web application and I got no users in my database, so I'd like to let users to login in my application using specific domain, for example asd@mydomain.com and then enter current password for this account.
any ideas?

Comment: Why you add maven tag?

Comment: My application is written using maven

Comment: Your application is not written using maven, it is build using maven.

Comment: Your question is not really clear. How would your application know a user his current password?

Comment: Its actually a bad security practice.. you could always ask them to register and login or prompt them to show invalid user/password if someone is doing a brute-force attack.

Comment: this is private web application,for specific company, which has own domain